# Aligning Menu Group to Menu Item

Tags: java, css, jsf, richfaces, seam

I'm using Seam and Richfaces to make a menu bar.
The code is like this:

```
<rich:dropDownMenu showDelay="250" hideDelay="0" submitMode="none">
        <f:facet name="label">Tools</f:facet>

        <rich:menuItem>
            <s:link view="/pages/tools/ppaParameters/PpaParametersEdit.xhtml" value="Parameters" id="PpaParametersId" includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
        </rich:menuItem>

        <rich:menuGroup value="Security">
            <rich:menuItem>
                <s:link view="/pages/tools/security/ppaModule/PpaModuleEdit.xhtml" value="Module" id="PpaModuleId" includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
            </rich:menuItem>
        </rich:menuGroup>

    </rich:dropDownMenu>
```

How can I make the menu item aligns to its "father"?

[image]

Ferramentas = Tools

Segurança = Security

Módulo = Module

Comment: did you compare your code to the demo source? http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dropDownMenu.jsf?c=menuGroup&tab=usage

Comment: I'll try to make it like the demo source tomorrow once I start to work, hopefully it will work.

Comment: I tried it and still didn't work.

Comment: pringlesinn, instead of s.link can you try with menuItem's action property?

Comment: i'll do it once i get into my work, and i'll let you know

Comment: This is more a CSS than JSF issue. For the ones who don't know RichFaces in depth (read: who can't tell the generated HTML from top of head), consider posting both the generated HTML and CSS so that the CSS experts can assist in finetuning the CSS.

Comment: Does this happen on all browsers or just a specific one?

Comment: I haven't tried another browser, didn't think it should have this difference. I use FireFox though.. I'll try some browser else.

Comment: @zinan.yumak: i've tried this, still didn't work.

Comment: I added display:block to cssStyle and it kinda worked. Not perfectly, but better than before...

Answer (score 1):

best way for styling is to use chrome dev tool included in it or firebug with firefox to tell which exact styles are being used with which element.

try to set align to inherit

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me so often you'd think I'd have learned by now: make sure your menu is surrounded by  `<h:form></h:form>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get a it on the website as a test one, i think WE can try it out... i would say get Firefox, and Firebug and do some workaround. That should help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the positioning of the menu items to absolute. This will make it position according to its parent. Then tweaking with the margins will get it in the desired location.

Comment: welcome and if you cab add some code examples to make your answer clearer.